# AndroidStudio Editor problems

Tags: editor, android-studio

Why in my java editor, text style doesn't like in preference.

[Editor](http://d.pr/i/SP6s)

[Preference](http://d.pr/i/Ff7l)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in Android Studio 0.2.0 by changing API from API 18: Android 4.3 to API 17: Android 4.2.2

This is under the android icon menu in the top right of the design window.

this was a solution from http://www.hankcs.com/program/mobiledev/idea-this-version-of-the-rendering-library-is-more-recent-than-your-version-of-intellij-idea-please-update-intellij-idea.html which required a Google translation into English.